# Export To Excel Work while debugging my MVC C#.Net application, but not when I publish and deploy it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I have an C# .Net MVC Application. I have done code for `Export to Excel` for Exporting data stored in `datatable`. I have stored the `datatable` in session until user press export button. When user press on export I fetch data from `datatable` via Ajax Call and export it. I have also kept a message when data exported successfully.

The problem is its works fine while debugging the application, but when I deploy the application it doesn't works. But it shows success message instead of error message. The other ajax calls in application for fetching data or storing data works fine.

I tried to debug the deployed application; exception occurs at line
`Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();`

the exception is

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was caught
  Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

The Export to Excel function

```
public static void ExportExcel(this DataTable Tbl, string ExcelFilePath = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Tbl == null || Tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                    //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                // column headings
                for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = Tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Bold = true;
                    workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Size = 12;
                }

                // rows
                for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // to do: format datetime values before printing
                    for (int j = 0; j < Tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Tbl.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }
                //int k = Tbl.Rows.Count;
                // check fielpath
                if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workSheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                        excelApp.Quit();
                        //MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"+ ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"+ ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message); 
            }
        }
```

This is code to call the function

```
public ActionResult JsonExportToExcel()
        {
            DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["filterCRMRequestDatatable"];
            ExportToExcel.ExportExcel(table, "");
            var result = "true";
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The ajax call code

```
$("#ExportToExcel").click(function () {
                //blur page
                $('#loading_div').removeClass("loading-css-back").addClass("loading-css-front");
                $('#loading_div').fadeIn();
                $('#Full_page_content').removeClass("main-div-front").addClass("main-div-back");
                $('#Full_page_content').fadeOut();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/FilterCRMRequest/JsonExportToExcel/',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Data Exported Successfully");
                        //active the page
                        $('#loading_div').removeClass("loading-css-front").addClass("loading-css-back");
                        $('#loading_div').fadeOut();
                        $('#Full_page_content').removeClass("main-div-back").addClass("main-div-front");
                        $('#Full_page_content').fadeIn();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, props) {
                        if (xhr.status == 401) {
                            alert("Session Expired. Please Login Again");
                            window.location.href = "/CRMLogin/LogOn";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Sorry some Error occured. Please Try again.");
                            //active the page
                            $('#loading_div').removeClass("loading-css-front").addClass("loading-css-back");
                            $('#loading_div').fadeOut();
                            $('#Full_page_content').removeClass("main-div-back").addClass("main-div-front");
                            $('#Full_page_content').fadeIn();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on why this 'doesn't work'? Do you receive any kind of error on screen for example.

Comment: that is the problem it doesn't shows any error. I had kept a alert after success of data export via ajax call in ajax success. It doesn't export but gives the alert of data exported successfully.

Comment: @JamieKeeling I tried to debug the deployed application and found exception occurs while creating new Excel.Application(). I updated details in questions...

Comment: If you look at the exception you can see this: "Access is denied.". Have you checked that the correct permissions are in place? A quick google should get you on the right track and there are similar questions on SO regarding that error in particular.

Comment: @JamieKeeling I solved this error. It needed to enable ASP.NET Impersonation and I did that now it gives new exception `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`... I searched for this error too and it says excel worksheet index starts from 1 not 0.. and I have taken index from 1 only but only this exception occurs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you throwing any exception or returning any error code - that might be, why you see the success message still.

The access-denied can be a permission problem. Do you have MS Excel installed on the server where you are deploying the application? - Also I got an Access Denied after switching from Server 2003 to Server 2012 and couldn't resolve the issue anymore. Even I found several places, where you could change permissions for WebSites to access MS-Office applications, none of them helped.

In the end I found several articles, that you shouldn't use Office Interop on the server, because:

- It uses the actual Office Application in the end

  - That makes it slow and resource consuming
  - It's hard to handle multiple requests at the same time
  - If the code fails, the application might keep running => it might never work again, until you restart the process

You might want to consider using a .net implementation of apache POI - [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). With this library you can manipulate Excel, Word and PowerPoint files.
If you are ok with using the new xml-based Excel Files (xlsx) you can use also directly [Microsofts OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx) or a wrapper around this library - [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)